# What python function is this SciPy tutorial referring to?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

SciPy's website has a tutorial that references a python function `source` that lists the source code of functions written in python, but I cannot use it in python or find documentation for it online. The reference is at the bottom of [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html) page. I see that the `inspect` module has similar functions but I'm still curious as to what function in what module they are referring to.

Comment: For anyone interested, it is mentioned at the bottom of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html

Comment: Link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.source.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.source` is a utility function in `numpy`. This can be called on any numpy/scipy or Python function or class, though compiled built-ins won't show anything.

The scipy and numpy API docs also have a `[source]` link that takes you to a source file.

I think np.source is relatively new, but as a long time `ipython` user I've been getting the same information with its `??` magic.

`np.source(np.source)` gives me

```
def source(object, output=sys.stdout):
    """
    ...
    """
    # Local import to speed up numpy's import time.
    import inspect
    try:
        print("In file: %s\n" % inspect.getsourcefile(object), file=output)
        print(inspect.getsource(object), file=output)
    except:
        print("Not available for this object.", file=output)
```

`In [425]: np.source??` shows the same thing but with some color coding.

Comment: I'd upvote again if I could for `np.source(np.source)`  :)